# Using Jquery Datepicker works on one page, not on another, in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I have a rails application.  On two different html pages, I would like to use jquery's datepicker. The first time I use this, it works just fine:

in my html:

```
<input id="kid_dob" name="kid[dob]" type="text" />
```

in my javascript:

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#kid_dob').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '-16:c'
    })({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });

  }).call(this);
```

(This is actually written in CoffeeScript, the JavaScript that I show above has been processed by rails).

This works fine: the datepicker calendar does appear when I click on the `kid_dob` text field.

However, on another page I have the html

```
<input id="reservable_history_start_date" name="reservable_history[start_date]" type="text" />
```

and the javascript (which is exactly the same except for `kid_dob` being replaced by `reservable_history_start_date`)

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#reservable_history_start_date').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '-16:c'
    })({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

And yet, in this second instance, the datepicker calendar does not appear.  Also, when I use the options inspector, in the first working case, the scrollover text is `input#kid_dob.hasDatepicker`, but in the not working case, the scrollover text is simply `input#reservable_history_start_date` (with no `hasDatepicker`).

Also, here are the `require` statements from my `application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

What am I doing wrong?!  Must be something different between the two html files, but I'm at a loss. Any hints are much appreciated.

This is all part of a rails 4.0.0 application, the output of `ruby -v` is
   ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
I am using ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the contents of your application.js file?

Comment: Sure, edited into original post

Comment: Does it work if you reload the second page? (could be a turbolinks related problem)

Comment: No.  I also tried adding and removing `//= require turbolinks` from application.js. Sorry.

Comment: see browser console if there is any js error exists?

Comment: Indeed. `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`.  Also, I've updated my `jquery` gem to version 3.0.0 (used to be 2.3.0), and now datepicker doesn't work in both my examples above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding below functions to your code,because the datepicker may not be loading.

```
$(document).on('page:load')
$(document).ready();
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.  Turns out, the error console (ctrl+shift+j) is incredibly helpful.  There was a null string being passed to `getElementById()`, from some code inside `jquery-rails`.  By methodically removing every line in my `application.js` file, until all I had was the `\\= require jquery-rails` line left, I could get that error to go away.  Then I slowly added one library at a time, until I found what was wrong (as I was sure that `jquery-rails` couldn't have such a simple bug).  Turns out that my version of `jquery-rails` and `bootstrap` had a clash - so I upgraded my version of `bootstrap`, and the `getElementByID()` problem was fixed, and now `datepicker` can work in both instances.